# Permission problems? Can't see my uncommitted changes in GitAhead

Tags: gitahead

I'm pretty new to the unix world coming from Windows 10 and starting to get comfortable with my new Debian based Voyager OS.

I have pretty much everything up and running but looking for an alternative of Sourcetree I found GitAhead looking promising as it is freeware.
It installed just fine and I could easily connect my works repository and also, fetch changes.

But when it came to my first merge I already had a hard time, finally solving it within PyCharm. Now that I'd like to view and commit my changes with GitAhead, my uncommited changes aren't displayed in GitAheads uncommited changes view.

Is there anything I'm missing? It looks to me like there's some kind of permission problem or why wouldn't GitAhead show me my uncommitted changes?

Edit:

[GitAhead GUI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYh9E.png)

Screenshot showing the functionality I'm missing on my other repositories.
This was taken from a fresh repository to demonstrate what my question is about.
As you can see I can select "uncommitted changes", select items on the right side and commit and finally push them. Just not in my companies repositories.

Edit2:

[current changelist in my IDE, showing 4 green (new) files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqob8.png)

[command line # git status, showing 4 added (new) files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piHZk.png)

[GitAhead, showing current branches uncommitted changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiDPk.png)

it should display 4 new files and 5 modified, as my IDE and git status do

Comment: I think it would be useful if you provide a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just created a dummy project to make some screenshots and all of the sudden the uncommitted tab actually had some uncommitted changes to show, commit and push.

I'm totally confused now why the hell a fresh repository works as intended by the gitahead developers and my companies repository won't show changes at all, nor let me commit or push my changes

Comment: What about clicking refresh button or CTRL+R? If you go to the console and run `git status`, Does it show the changes there? If you can post a screenshot with the actual error would be nice, obscuring any sensitive information of course.

Comment: Thanks for hanging on with me. I attached 3 more screenshots, as you wished. But you won't see an error or something like this, I can refresh CTRL+R without issues, my changes just won't appear

Comment: That's weird... I suggest you create an issue ticket at https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues, attaching the screenshots. I tried to find something related but did not find anything. Just out of curiosity, Are you using the same window for your repositories and the dummy project and just by selecting a different project makes the Stage and Commit areas to appear?

Comment: Installed GitAhead today, because I was tired of SourceTree slowness, and it impressed me, but unfortunately I experienced exactly the same problem - uncommitted changes were not visible.